# Is there a way to make an installer which can install multiple msis downloading from internet?

Tags: installation, wix, bootstrapper

Just like WiX installer, I wanna distribute a small setup.exe, while installing, the setup.exe  can download the demanded msis from a specified server.
If anyone know how to do, code sample is better.

The below codes can be compiled successfully, but the WixBA UI doesn't display.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id='ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost'>
  <Payload Name='BootstrapperCore.config' SourceFile='WixBA.BootstrapperCore.config' />

  <Payload SourceFile='WixBA.dll' />
  <Payload SourceFile='License.htm' />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>

<Variable Name='InstallFolder' Type='string' Value='[ProgramFilesFolder]Test' />
    <Chain>
  <MsiPackage Id='sevenz' Vital='yes' Name='data\7z.msi' SourceFile='data\7z.msi' >
    <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLFOLDER' Value='[InstallFolder]' />
  </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
</Bundle>
```

Answer (score 1):

The WiX toolset supports this using the Burn engine. The source code is all available in src\burn\engine (in particular, you'll want to look at downloadengine.cpp).

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I could not compile the codes successfully, it seems the build.cmd files are missing. Could you please give me a simple sample? I tried to use WixBA.dll to show the UI, it can be compiled successfully, but when I run the exe, nothing will display. I attached my test codes.